# tkinter python, animacion de botones Buttons

Tags: python, tkinter, botón, animación, hover

tengo una pregunta , como hago para poder animar un boton en tkinter si se puede  o en  python , q al pasar el mouse por encima reaccione y se genere una animacion .
eso creo que se le llama 'efecto hover' , quiero que eso suceda en python , si se puede que sea en tkinter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo manejando los eventos `<Enter>` y `<Leave>`:

```py
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')

button = Button(root, text='Ejemplo', padx=20, pady=20, bg='white')

button.pack(expand=True)

button.bind('<Enter>', lambda e: e.widget.config(bg='red'))
button.bind('<Leave>', lambda e: e.widget.config(bg='white'))

root.mainloop()
```

En este ejemplo el formulario tiene un botón de color blanco. Cuando el usuario pase el cursor por encima del botón, este se coloreará de rojo:

`button.bind('<Enter>', lambda e: e.widget.config(bg='red'))`

Y cuando el cursor salga del botón volverá a colorearse de blanco:

`button.bind('<Leave>', lambda e: e.widget.config(bg='white'))`

Puedes modificar cualquier propiedad del botón, al que accedes mediante `e.widget` dentro del *manejador del evento*.

En el siguiente ejemplo además aumentamos el *padding* del botón cuando se dispara el evento `<Enter>`, y lo restauramos al dispararse el evento `<Leave>`:

```py
from tkinter import *


def on_enter(e):
    e.widget.config(bg='red')
    e.widget.config(padx=20, pady=20)

def on_leave(e):
    e.widget.config(bg='white')
    e.widget.config(padx=0, pady=0)


root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')

button = Button(root, text='Ejemplo', bg='white')

button.pack(expand=True)

button.bind('<Enter>', on_enter)
button.bind('<Leave>', on_leave)

root.mainloop()
```

Puedes acceder a los atributos de un *widget* utilizando su método `cget`, de manera que si quisieras modificar el texto del botón al pasar el cursor por encima podrías hacer algo así:

```py
def on_enter(e):
    e.widget.config(text=e.widget.cget('text').upper())

def on_leave(e):
    e.widget.config(text=e.widget.cget('text').capitalize())
```

Saludos!

Comment: muchas gracias , estoy avanzando paso a paso con estas ayudas.

Comment: me encanto , para  mi es algo avanzado , para usd debe de ser algo sencillo , me encanto ver ese efecto , muchas gracias.

Comment: Con práctica se convertirá en algo sencillo para tí. Todos empezamos sin saber nada. Mucho ánimo! :)